# Strange error when compiling using "mpic++ -std=c++11"

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, mpi

I'm trying to compile some code on a Linux system. There always are strange errors when I use the command `mpic++ -std=c++11`. The code in a file named "HW.cpp" is as follows:

```
#include<mpi.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int myid,numprocs;
    int namelen;
    char processor_name[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&myid);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numprocs);
    MPI_Get_processor_name(processor_name,&namelen);

    cout<<"Hello World! Process "<<myid<<" of "<<numprocs<<endl;

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Every thing was fine when I used the command `mpic++ HW.cpp`, but when I do this, `mpic++ -std=c++11 HW.cpp`, I get errors like the following:

```
In file included from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ext/alloc_traits.h(36),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/basic_string.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/string(52),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/ios_base.h(41),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ios(42),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ostream(38),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/iostream(39),
             from HM.cpp(2):
/WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/alloc_traits.h(251): error: expected a ">"
      = typename __construct_helper<_Tp, _Args...>::type;
                                              ^
In file included from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ext/alloc_traits.h(36),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/basic_string.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/string(52),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/ios_base.h(41),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ios(42),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ostream(38),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/iostream(39),
             from HM.cpp(2):
      detected during instantiation of type       "std::allocator_traits<_Alloc>::__has_construct<_Tp, _Args...>" at line 254
In file included from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ext/alloc_traits.h(36),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/basic_string.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/string(52),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/ios_base.h(41),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ios(42),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ostream(38),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/iostream(39),
             from HM.cpp(2):

In file included from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ext/alloc_traits.h(36),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/basic_string.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/string(52),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/ios_base.h(41),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ios(42),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ostream(38),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/iostream(39),
             from HM.cpp(2):
/WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/type_traits(133): error: not a class or struct name
  : public _B1
           ^
In file included from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ext/alloc_traits.h(36),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/basic_string.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/string(52),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/ios_base.h(41),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ios(42),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ostream(38),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/iostream(39),
             from HM.cpp(2):
      detected during:
In file included from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ext/alloc_traits.h(36),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/basic_string.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/string(52),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/ios_base.h(41),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ios(42),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ostream(38),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/iostream(39),
             from HM.cpp(2):
        instantiation of class "std::__and_<_B1> [with _B1=<error-type>]" at line 2108
In file included from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ext/alloc_traits.h(36),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/basic_string.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/string(52),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/ios_base.h(41),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ios(42),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ostream(38),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/iostream(39),
             from HM.cpp(2):
        instantiation of type "std::_Require<<error-type>>" at line 254 of "/WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/alloc_traits.h"
In file included from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ext/alloc_traits.h(36),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/basic_string.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/string(52),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/ios_base.h(41),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ios(42),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ostream(38),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/iostream(39),
             from HM.cpp(2):

In file included from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ext/alloc_traits.h(36),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/basic_string.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/string(52),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/ios_base.h(41),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ios(42),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ostream(38),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/iostream(39),
             from HM.cpp(2):
/WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/type_traits(2108): error: class "std::__and_<<error-type>>" has no member "value"
  using _Require = typename enable_if<__and_<_Cond...>::value>::type;
                                                        ^
In file included from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ext/alloc_traits.h(36),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/basic_string.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/string(52),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/ios_base.h(41),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ios(42),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ostream(38),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/iostream(39),
             from HM.cpp(2):
      detected during instantiation of type "std::_Require<<error-type>>" at line 254 of "/WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/alloc_traits.h"
In file included from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ext/alloc_traits.h(36),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/basic_string.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/string(52),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/ios_base.h(41),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ios(42),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ostream(38),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/iostream(39),
             from HM.cpp(2):

In file included from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ext/alloc_traits.h(36),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/basic_string.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/string(52),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/ios_base.h(41),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ios(42),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ostream(38),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/iostream(39),
             from HM.cpp(2):
/WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/type_traits(2108): error: class "std::enable_if<<error-constant>, void>" has no member "type"
  using _Require = typename enable_if<__and_<_Cond...>::value>::type;
                                                                ^
In file included from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ext/alloc_traits.h(36),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/basic_string.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/string(52),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/ios_base.h(41),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ios(42),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ostream(38),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/iostream(39),
             from HM.cpp(2):
      detected during instantiation of type "std::_Require<<error-type>>" at line 254 of "/WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/alloc_traits.h"
In file included from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ext/alloc_traits.h(36),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/basic_string.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/string(52),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/locale_classes.h(40),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/ios_base.h(41),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ios(42),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/ostream(38),
             from /WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/iostream(39),
             from HM.cpp(2):

/WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/stl_iterator_base_types.h(154): error: class "std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>" has no member "iterator_category"
    typedef typename _Iterator::iterator_category iterator_category;
                                ^
      detected during:
        instantiation of class "std::__iterator_traits<_Iterator, void> [with _Iterator=std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>]" at line 163
        instantiation of class "std::iterator_traits<_Iterator> [with _Iterator=std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>]" at line 4865 of "/WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/basic_string.h"
        instantiation of "std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> &&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> &&) [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc=std::allocator<char>]" at line 343 of "/WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/system_error"

/WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/type_traits(1492): error: class "std::__is_convertible_helper<<error-type>, std::input_iterator_tag, false>" has no member class "type"
  : public __is_convertible_helper<_From, _To>::type
                                                ^
      detected during:
        instantiation of class "std::is_convertible<_From, _To> [with _From=<error-type>, _To=std::input_iterator_tag]" at line 4865 of "/WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/basic_string.h"
        instantiation of "std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> &&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> &&) [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc=std::allocator<char>]" at line 343 of "/WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/system_error"

/WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/type_traits(1492): error: not a class or struct name
  : public __is_convertible_helper<_From, _To>::type
           ^
      detected during:
        instantiation of class "std::is_convertible<_From, _To> [with _From=<error-type>, _To=std::input_iterator_tag]" at line 4865 of "/WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/bits/basic_string.h"
        instantiation of "std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> std::operator+(std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> &&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc> &&) [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc=std::allocator<char>]" at line 343 of "/WORK/app/gcc/5.2.0/include/c++/5.2.0/system_error"

compilation aborted for HM.cpp (code 2)
```

I am really confused with these errors.

Comment: Please show us a [MCVE]

Comment: What does `mpic++ -v` give you? Can you compile a single line "`
#include<iostream>`" file?

Comment: `mpic++ -v` gives `mpicxx for MPICH version 3.1.3
icpc version 14.0.2 (gcc version 4.8.0 compatibility)`. It gives same errros if compile a single line "` #include<iostream>`" file.

Comment: Thanks you, guys! I have figured it out! I use the command `module load MPI/Gnu/MPICH/3.2-gcc4.9.2-dyn` before compiling and it works!